# Making simple unix shell using fork,execvp

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

printf(*arg);
       execvp(*arg, arg);
Here printf() statement prints value= ls.But when  running program execvp gives there is no such file or directory.
 else if (pid == 0) {

```
   printf(*arg);
   execvp(*arg, arg);  

    char* error = strerror(errno);
    printf("shell: %s: %s\n", arg[0], error);
    return 0; 
  if(execvp(arg[0], arg)<0)
   { 
    printf("***ERROR: execution failedn\n");
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of the second printf where you print `arg[0]`? A common error when writing a shell is to forget to trim the newline character from the end of the line of input read from the user.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code are two examples of how to use `execvp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *args[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};

    /* an example with a decleared array containing the commande */
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(args[0], args);
    }

    /* another example where the commande was passed to main */
    printf("argv[0] is the programme/executable name!\nargv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> The `execv()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()` functions provide an array of
> pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
> available to the new program.
>
> **The first argument, by convention,
> should point to the filename associated** with the file being executed.
> **The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer**.